# Why doesn't this inheritance work?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have a class that derives from TcpClient, e.g.

```
class ZClient : TcpClient
{
    public byte[] Buffer { get; set; }
    public Queue<byte[]> Queue {get; set;}
}
```

And a method that creates a TcpClient

```
...

TcpListener listener = ar.AsyncState as TcpListener;
ZClient client = listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar) as ZClient;
```

The object 'client' is null when I cast listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar), which normally returns TcpClient, as ZClient.  Is what I am trying to do illegal?

**Update**:  Would it be possible to set the properties of the base class of ZClient equal to the TcpClient that's being passed in via the constructor, as to avoid having to have an additional property to reference the TcpClient?  e.g.

```
public ZClient(TcpClient client)
{
   base = client;  // I'm aware this doesn't work.
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a "has a" rather than "is a" relationship between TcpClient and ZClient

```
class ZClient
{
    public ZClient(TcpClient client) 
    {
        this.client = client;
    }
    public TcpClient client {get; set;}
    public byte[] Buffer { get; set; }
    public Queue<byte[]> Queue {get; set;}
}
```

Then you can delegate the calls to the underlying TcpClient

Answer (score 6):

Because it's backwards. TcpClient doesn't contain a Buffer or a Queue, because it's not a ZClient. Apples are Fruit, but not all Fruit are Apples.

You'll need some sort of explicit conversion. You could provide a ZClient constructor that accepted a TcpClient, or an extension method on TcpClient that returns a ZClient. Either of these will probably require making ZClient a wrapper class for a TcpClient, instead of a child of ZClient.

Comment: It's like the saying, "Insanity is hereditary -- you get it from your children."

Answer (score 4):

All `ZClient`s are `TcpCplient`s but not all `TcpClient`s are `ZClient`s<sup>*</sup>. The `TcpClient` returned by `TcpListener.EndAcceptTcpClient` is a `TcpClient` that can not be used as a `ZClient`. You could wrap the resulting `TcpClient`. I would suggest a constructor of the form

```
private readonly TcpClient;
public ZClient(TcpClient tcpClient) {
    this.tcpClient = tcpClient;
}
```

<sup>*</sup>: Perhaps a different example will help

```
class Animal { }
class Cat {
    public int NumberOfLives { get; private set; }
    public Cat() { NumberOfLives = 9; }
}
```

Should you be able to cast (using `as`) any object returned by a method returning an `Animal` to a `Cat`? Not all `Animal`s have feet just like not all `TcpClient`s have a `byte[]` named `Buffer` or a `Queue<byte[]>` named `Queue`. Therefore, you can't think of a generic `TcpClient` as a `ZClient` just like you can't think of a generic `Animal` as a `Cat`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is what I am trying to do illegal?

Yes. How could `TcpListener` know how to come up with a `ZClient`? If it did, what would the `Buffer` and `Queue` properties do?

Answer (score 0):

`listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar)` is returning to you a `TcpClient`.  You can't take a `TcpClient` and pretend that it's a `ZClient`.  That's not how inheritance works.

In short:

- All `ZClient`s are `TcpClient`s by definition.
- Not all `TcpClient`s are `ZClient`s.

For example, a horse is an animal.  Not all animals are horses.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting a TcpClient from the listener, then the listener is just going to return you a TcpClient like it always does.  You are never newing up a ZClient.  TcpListener doesn't know anything about your new class so it can't create it.  If you just want to have an object that adds functionality to a TcpClient, you might want to just use composition as opposed to inheritance.  Simplly have a ZClient that wraps a TcpClient by storing one internally, and add any functionality you would like.